# Simple OCaml data structure failing with unbound parameter error

Tags: class, types, polymorphism, ocaml

I have this really basic class in OCaml:

```
class handler rule callback methods =
    object(self)
        method matches test_string test_method =
            let r = Str.regexp rule in
            match Str.string_match r test_string 0 with
            | false -> false
            | true -> methods = [] || List.exists (fun nth_method -> nth_method = test_method) methods
    end
```

But I can't get it to compile (the file is handler.ml):

```
File "handler.ml", line 1, characters 6-339:
Error: Some type variables are unbound in this type:
     class handler :
       string ->
       'a -> 'b list -> object method matches : string -> 'b -> bool end
   The method matches has type string -> 'b -> bool where 'b is unbound
```

This doesn't make sense to me because it seems pretty obvious by my comparison that I'm expecting `test_method` and any element of `methods` to be the same type. Furthermore, the type system is obviously seeing that they are both type `'b`, so why is it having an issue? (For the record, `methods` is a list of strings.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's shrink this example to a smaller one with the same issue:

```
# class c things = object(self) method m thing = List.mem thing things end;;
Error: Some type variables are unbound in this type:
         class c : 'a list -> object method m : 'a -> bool end
       The method m has type 'a -> bool where 'a is unbound
```

Note that the error is about an unbound type variable, not a type mismatch.

The problem has to do with the class definition. If you define a standalone object, it's fine:

```
fun things -> object(self) method m thing = List.mem thing things end;;
- : 'a list -> < m : 'a -> bool > = <fun>
```

Note how the type of the object is polymorphic. A class is a type, not a type scheme. When you try to define `c`, the type variable `'a` remains unbound: the class definition is polymorphic in this type variable. Therefore what you are defining is not a class with a type, but a family of classes parametrized over a type, in the same way that a type scheme is a family of types parametrized over a type.

Ocaml lets you define such parametrized classes, but you need to declare the parameter explicitly:

```
# class ['a] c (things : 'a list) = object(self) method m thing = List.mem thing things end;;
class ['a] c : 'a list -> object method m : 'a -> bool end
```

You can verify that the type corresponding to this class is a parametrized type with one argument:

```
# type 'a t = 'a c;;
type 'a t = 'a c
```

You write that `methods` should be a list of strings, but in the code you've written, nothing constrains it. If you want to restrict the definition, you'll need to add a type annotation (which you can remove once you've written more code that constrains `methods` to be a list of strings). You can put the type annotation wherever you like — on `matches`, on `test_method`, on `methods`, …

```
# class c (things : string list) = object(self) method m thing = List.mem thing things end;;
class c : string list -> object method m : string -> bool end
```

See the [Ocaml manual §3.10 Objects — Parametrized classes](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/objectexamples.html) for more information.